# DIV tag becomes hidden "forever" after it was shown with fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I see a strange behavior.
Please save this as an HTML-file and open it.
You will see only "Inline" because "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" has `"display: none"` for `media="screen"`. Perfect. Then invoke browser's "Print preview" function. You will see both "Inline" AND "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" because the latter has `"display: inline"` for `media="print"`. Perfect again. That's the behavior I need. And now click on the "Inline" link. A fancyBox with "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" will appear. Close this fancyBox. And invoke browser's "Print preview" function again. You will see only "Inline", i.e. now you will NOT see "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet". What a heck?! Does anybody know the reason?! is it a bug in fancyBox?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .hiddenContent {
      display: none
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
    .hiddenContent {
      display: inline
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a class="fancybox" href="#inline1">Inline</a>
  <div id="inline1" class="hiddenContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Dhiraj Bodicherla**'s suggestion worked for me. Just add "`!important`" in the CSS on Print function. (But I used block instead of inline)

```
$("#print").on("click", function(){
   var theWork =  window.open('','PrintWindow');
   var html = "<html><head>";
   html += "<style>.printable{display:block !important;} .notprintable{display:none;} </style>";            
   html += "</head>";   
   html += "<body><div id='myprint'>" + $('.fancybox-inner').clone().html();    
   html += "</div>";        
   html += "</body></html>";    
   theWork.document.open();
   theWork.document.write(html);
   theWork.document.close();
   theWork.print();
   theWork.close();
});
```

- "#print" is your button id.
- ".printable" is your div tag class name that you want to print.
- ".notprintable" is your div tag class name that you DON'T want to print.

Answer (score 1):

Using `!important` should do it

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
   .hiddenContent {
       display: inline !important;
   }
</style>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this works in the HTML code excerpt I listed in the first post, but to some reason does NOT work in the real ("big") code of my web-site. Currently I'm trying to find out any difference between these two codes...

Comment: Well, in the real ("big") code this "!important" keywotd works too, but... after fancyBox closes, the "#inline1" DIV is moved to the end of the document! At first I didn't notice it - I thought that this DIV just remained invisible. But when I scrolled the "Print Preview" browser's view to the end, I saw my DIV tag there. Well, that's certainly a bug of fancyBox. Seems it occurs only with a big and complex HTML, and in a small HTML (like the one in my first post) everything is OK.

Comment: If you have a solution, please add [Solved] after your question :)

Comment: No, I still don't have a solution. My real web-page becomes in fact unprintable after any fancyBox was used at least once!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery sets display:none in the style attribute of the elements it doesn't want shown - even if the sheets already specify this. Try cloning the elements you want shown before passing them to the fancybox.

Comment: Thank you. How should I perform this cloning?

Comment: I googled out the following code:
`$.fancybox({
  content: $("#myElement").clone()
});`
- but in my case I cannot hardcode for the tag name ("#myElement") because I am using one and the same fancyBox for dozens of links on my site. Or am I supposed to start using dozens of fancyBoxes as well? hope not :) So, how can I clone the target element without hardcoding for its name?